# How do I print the value of a specific item in a list?

Tags: python, list

How do I print the value of animals from the list?

```
 [{'Url': 'https://www.somewebsite.html',
      'Fruits': [],
      'Animals': ['Fox'],
      'Cars': ['Toyota']},
```

Comment: Please explain your question and add more detail.

Comment: Why do you have a list with one dict in it? `dct[0]["Animals"]`?

Answer (score 1):

Thats is an dictionary inside list, so

```
l = [{'Url': 'https://www.somewebsite.html',
  'Fruits': [],
  'Animals': ['Fox'],
  'Cars': ['Toyota']},
print(l[0]) # return dictionary 
print(l[0]['Animals']) # return the list  '['Fox']', that can be accessed by index 0.
```

Comment: PEP-8 suggests never naming a variable `l`. It looks too much like `1`, `I` and `i`. Prefer `lst`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point of a list in there so I think what you are looking for is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {
    'key': 'value',
    ...
}
```

This is the easiest way to have paired items and to have a keyword that will give you more information about something. For example it could be used as information about products in a store where you can get the price and category for example.

To access these values you simply use this line of code: `d['key']` or `d.get('key')`

So for this example you want to organize your items inside a dictionary like this:

```
items = {
    'Fruits': [],
    'Animals': ['Fox'],
    'Cars': ['Toyota']
}

print(items['Animals'])  # This gives you the list that in this example looks like this: ['Fox']

animals = items['Animals']  # This stores the list from above in a variable

print(items['Animals'][0])  # Out: 'Fox'
print(items.get('Animals')[0])  # Out: 'Fox'
print(animals[0])  # Out: 'Fox'
```